# Create a column in a spark dataframe from computing a value of the row with a whole column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing

I have a dataframe :

```
|id|value|
| 0|    1|
| 1|    3|
| 2|    9|
```

I want to apply a function on each row to create a new column. This function has to have a value of the row in parameter and the whole column as second parameter to generate a vector.

e.g. : A vector of sums of values from the column with the value of the row:

```py
def fu(myValue, myColumn):
    return [myValue + i for i in myColumn]
```

To have :

```
|id|value|sums_in_column|
| 0|    1|    [2, 4, 10]|
| 1|    3|    [3, 6, 12]|
| 2|    9|  [10, 12, 18]|
```

I know, I can pass one or more values from a row to compute a new column using `withColumn` and `udf` to parallelize the execution. But I don't understand how I could pass the column as an argument? Is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure it should be "20" in `[10, 12, 20]`?

Comment: You're right, it's corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a whole column data to an UDF because the Spark engine is splitting the computation and the data across several servers/executors.

If you can adapt your algorithm to work on the executor local subset of the column values, you can use [RDD.mapPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=mappartitions) to execute a single function over a complete partition of data.

Alternatively, if you know your column data can fit in your executors memory, you can first [DataFrame.collect()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect) the column data and use [SparkContext.broadcast()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=mappartitions#pyspark.SparkContext.broadcast) to copy it to all executors and use a reference to the [broadcasted variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=mappartitions#pyspark.Broadcast) in your UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
>>> d = [{'id': 0, 'value': 1},{'id': 1, 'value': 3},{'id': 2, 'value': 9}]
>>> df0 = spark.createDataFrame(d)
>>> df0.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  0|    1|
|  1|    3|
|  2|    9|
+---+-----+
```

Step 1: Use `collect_list()` function to create an array of all values in column `value`, and add this array as a column to the initial dataframe

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> arr = df0.agg(collect_list(df.value).alias('arr_column'))
>>> df1 = df0.crossJoin(arr)
>>> df1.show()
+---+-----+-------------+
| id|value|   arr_column|
+---+-----+-------------+
|  0|    1|    [1, 3, 9]|
|  1|    3|    [1, 3, 9]|
|  2|    9|    [1, 3, 9]|
+---+-----+-------------+
```

Cross-join will essentially broadcast the array to all executors, so watch out for the data size you want to apply it to. (You may also be required to set `spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true` explicitly when creating Spark context, because Spark doesn't like cross-joins for that exact reason.)

Step 2: register your `fu` function as Spark UDF

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> fu_udf = udf(fu, ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

Step3: Use this UDF to increment array elements

```
>>> df3 = df1.withColumn('sums_in_column',fu_udf(df1.value,df1.arr_column))
>>> df3.show()
+---+-----+-------------+--------------+
| id|value|   arr_column|sums_in_column|
+---+-----+-------------+--------------+
|  0|    1|    [1, 3, 9]|    [2, 4, 10]|
|  1|    3|    [1, 3, 9]|    [4, 6, 12]|
|  2|    9|    [1, 3, 9]|  [10, 12, 18]|
+---+-----+-------------+--------------+
```